# Iterations over items of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have read many times that iterations should be avoided in dataframes so I have been trying the "better ways", such as applying functions, but I get stuck with the following error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

I need to run iterative calculations across various row items and get updated values. Here is an simplified example, but the real case has a lot of math in it hence why functions are preferred:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30,40], 'B':[4,3,2,1]})

def match_col(A,B):
    while A != B:
        B = B + 1

df.apply(lambda x: match_col(df['A'],df['B']),axis=1)
```

Basically, I need for each row to use a number of items, run iterative calcs, and output new/updated items. Where am I getting the logic wrong?

Comment: If the function only depends on the current row, then you don't need `apply`. You can just do vector operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead do:

```
df.apply(lambda x: match_col(x['A'],x['B']),axis=1)
```

Because you're applying the function over each row, the row's values are what need to be passed to `match_col` and not entire series e.g. `df['A']`.

You also need to `return` something from your function:

```
def match_col(A,B):
    while A != B:
        B = B + 1
    return B
```

Then you'll get this result:

```
In [10]: df.apply(lambda x: match_col(x['A'],x['B']),axis=1)                    
Out[10]: 
0    10
1    20
2    30
3    40
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I realise now the error came from using "df" instead of "x" to refer to the function's variables.

Answer (score 0):

I  did some changes in apply function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30,40], 'B':[1,3,2,1]})

def match_col(col):
    while col.A != col.B:
        col.B = col.B + 1
        return col.B


df.apply(match_col,axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
0    2
1    4
2    3
3    2
dtype: int64
```